# What are some kid-friendly dishes from Kenya?

Tags: african

Background: Last year, my kids' school play was The Sound Of Music. I was asked to make food for the cast party. No problem. My family is from Austria; I made schnitzel for 75. It's mentioned in one of the songs and, of course, I did not make it with noodles because nobody in Austria eats it that way.

The cast party was such a success (and everyone was thrilled with the themed food) that I was asked to do it again this year. My problem is that this year's play is The Lion King. What do I make? This is middle school in the US, so it's 6th - 8th graders.

Comment: I'm sorry but recipe requests are off topic here.

Comment: Suggested rephrase: What reliable literature can give an overview, including some intermediate level recipes, of Kenyan and general East African cuisine?

Comment: @rackandboneman resource requests aren't any better than recipe requests. "Which book should I use" isn't any different than "Which recipe should I use"...

Comment: Not asking for a recipe, but a list of dishes that are part of a regional cuisine.

Answer (score 4):

[The Kenyan Food Overview: 20 of Kenya’s Best Dishes by Mark Wiens](https://migrationology.com/kenyan-food-overview-20-of-kenyas-best-dishes/) should point you in the right direction. He lists ugali (cornmeal), irio (mashed peas and potatoes), githeri (beans and corn), pilau (spiced rice), stews (beef, goat, chicken, other animals), wali wa nazi (coconut rice), sukuma wiki (collard greens/kale), roasted maize (corn), bhajia (fried potatoes), mandazi (fried dough), Masala chips (french fries), chips Mayai (french fries and egg), coffee, and some cross-cultural items such as samosas and chapatis.

Masala chips might be very relatable to the children:

> The dish starts with a greasy plate of freshly deep fried french fries (chips). Tomato sauce, chili sauce, herbs, cilantro, and whatever else the chef decides are all added to the fries, coating them in a luscious sauce that will have you licking your fingers and the plate!

Answer (score 1):

To be on the safe side. I go with Jollo. A yam & peanut soup. Add some chunked pork belly.  Unless Muslim.  Then the last 15 min. add chunked fish. With a corn meal dish on the side. Or into S. Pacific area a rice side. Area from you might want to add a HOT pepper to the soup.

Comment: Would be simple to make a lot of, but I'd check for allergies first.